# Asus m5A97 RAID/AHCI configuration

Tags: raid, sata, ahci

I'm trying to RAID two SSD's in raid 0 to install games on, but I want to have my OS running off of my HDD (which it is currently installed on). I have the HDD plugged into SATA 5, and the SSD's plugged into SATA 2 and 3 (cable length).
When I set SATA 1-4 to raid, the only options I have for 5-6 is RAID or IDE. When I set SATA 1-4 to AHCI, I cannot set 5-6 to RAID. A simple, but annoying catch 22

How do I set SATA 5-6 to AHCI while maintaining RAID on 1-4?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Annoying I'm sure.  Something to try:

Put ports 1-4 into RAID mode, attach the HDD to one of those ports as well as the SSDs.  Create the wanted array with the SSDs and don't join the HDD to any array.

Ensure the HDD is set as a boot drive in the RAID config.

This should enable the AHCI/RAID controller's capabilities and benefits for the hard drive, even though it's not actually in an array.

Comment: I was hoping something like that was possible, I'll give that a shot and see if I can get it to work, thanks

Comment: Thid isn't working or I can't figure it out.  I ended up making the raid through windows disk manager, thanks anyway!